# Is there a way to have GNU screen automatically open a number of screens the first time it starts a new session?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I often have 5+ screens open for monitoring the server within one screen and it's somewhat annoying to have setup them all up again after a system restart. Usually there is 1 top process and a few tails for watching log files.

Is there a way to have screen automatically open a number of screens with certain commands executed in each scren?

Comment: Could you add a note indicating that this related to GNU Screen - it's very confusing to read otherwise...

Comment: @mh I added some more tags, thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can put this into your screenrc, eg.

```
screen -t Code 0
screen -t Chat 1 irssi
screen -t Shell 2
screen -t Remote 3 ssh user@host
screen -t screen4 4
```

Answer (score 4):

You can put the commands in a text file, and then specify that text file as your screenrc, screen will still inherit the entries from the system screenrc file in /etc.  The text file might look like:

```
zombie qr
screen -t sshToServer1 ssh Server1
screen -t logTail tail -f /var/log/foo
```

The Syntax is:

```
screen -t title <optional window number> command commandArguments
```

The zombie qr will make it so if you close that window, you can resurrect it by pressing r.  To specify the above text file:

```
screen -c textfile
```

If you want to name the screen session, and have reattach the name if there is already a detached session with the same name instead of starting a new one, use -R:

```
screen -R myScreenSession -c textfile
```

This way, you can save several different text files for different screen sessions.